# Excel: Matching unique values of File 1 with File 2 and copying a third variable onto file 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, transpose, vba

I'm looking to do the following in Excel:

In File 1, Column F (with header), I'd like to compare and match the values of File 2, Column A (with header). Column A has multiple duplicates, so only the first instance of a unique value is what needs to be compared to. If the two values match, I'd like to copy the cost value (which is summed using a SUMIF function) of Column L in File 2, and paste the numerical value onto Column K of File 1.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing some code?

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a pivot table that reads data from an external database (a.k.a. your File 1) does that get you started?